# First order statistic of folded normal

Tags: normal-distribution, order-statistics, chi-squared-distribution, folded-normal-distribution

Are there any good approximations or tail bounds for the first-order statistic of the folded normal, or the closely related chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom? It seems that the $n$-th order statistic is well studied (Gumbel), but not the minimum.

Answer (score 4):

One can obtain an exact closed-form solution:

If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $|X|$ has a folded Normal distribution with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Then, the pdf of the $1^{st}$ order statistic, in a sample of size $n$, is:

[image]

with domain of support on the positive real line,

where:

1. I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the nitty-gritties,
2. `Erf[z]` denotes the error function $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int _0^z e^{-t^2} d t$

To illustrate, here is a plot of the pdf of the sample minimum, when $\mu=2$, $\sigma=1$ and for various sample sizes $n$:

[image]